# Opening popup windows in HTML

Tags: html

I am working with web apps, and I am wondering if there is a way to open a link in an app-type window using HTML? Something like this:

```
<a href="link" target="_app">My App</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "app-type window"?  No browser controls?

Comment: As in a chrome or firefox web app

Comment: @Arlen, Is JavaScript not an option for you?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is an option, but if HTML has it, I'd rather use it.

Comment: @Pekka, http://bit.ly/QVThT4. I don't exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: Why the downvotes? A downvote isn't supposed to mean "nope, can't do that", is it?

Comment: I meant - why not Google it *first* before asking it as a question here? It's way faster, and as you can see, there's plenty of results that give you everything you need. Asking here should be for questions that *can't* be answered with a simple search.

Comment: @Pekka a little harsh perhaps..?  absense of evidence doesn't imply evidence of absense, after all.. :-)

Comment: @thebjorn It's nothing personal against the OP... one trivial question doesn't hurt anyone, and I'm not completely innocent of asking them myself. But if you have five hundred of them *every day*, you have a problem

Comment: @Pekka I think you might have misunderstood my point.. Just because you can't find anything on google, doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.  Granted, the OP didn't say he had tried google in his question (so a ding for "research effort", but it is certainly clear, and I imagine it could be useful for others wondering about this trivial question :-)

Comment: @thebjorn but that assumes that question has never been asked on Stack Overflow before. Check out the "Related" column to the right -  and that's only the first couple of dozen of what I'm sure is many hundreds or thousands of instances of the same question - and the many many duplicates in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=popup+window+html

Comment: @Pekka that's an entirely different argument, which is certainly valid (although I'm still intrigued by what the OP means by app-type window :-)

Comment: In Chrome: Wrench > Tools > Create Application Shortcut...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','MyWindow','width=600,height=300'); return false;">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: @PeterVR see the bottom example in the link you gave: `<a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','MyWindow','width=600,height=300'); return false;">Click Here</a>`

Comment: Sorry, I thought he meant the actual values (600, 300) had to be between apostrophes. You are absolutly right. My mistake.

Comment: Could you also say whether this can be done only using HTML? What you posted isn't just HTML, which is my original question, but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

`HTML` alone does not support this. You need to use some `JS`.

And also consider nowadays people use popup blocker in browsers.

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('document.aspx','mypopuptitle','width=600,height=400')">open popup</a>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Answer (score 9):

**I feel like this is the simplest way. (Feel free to change the width and height values).**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" 
target="popup" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
Link Text goes here...
</a>
```

Comment: I don't see `target="popup"` being a valid value for this attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#target

Answer (score 1):

Open a popup, a sample, link with in the same site.

```
 <a onclick="window.open('/Product/Product', 'popup', 'location=0,width=750,height=650,left=500,top=55'); return false;" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</a>
```