# I want to add popup window in html page. Example is at www.pu.edu.pk (online admission)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add a pop-up window in HTML page on its loading. The sample is at `www.pu.edu.pk`. Here the popup for 'online admission' occurs after loading on the website. Can anyone help, please?

Sincerest Regards!

Comment: `window.open("www.pu.edu.pk");`  I think you are looking for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that this is not a coding service. You should first try building it yourself.

Comment: Try to google your question before posting it, you will find what you want easily :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening popup windows in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812161/opening-popup-windows-in-html)

Comment: I have tried this one <a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://www.google.com','MyWindow','width=600,height=300'); return false;">Click Here</a> .. It works by clicking on 'Click Here' but I want to show this popup automatically in center of screen upon loading of an html page rather than clicking on some text.