# can not display database information on jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am trying to store multiple popup windows in a database table. When I display it in a jsp page I am getting an error 
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Unable to open a window with invalid URL

this is the code in the jsp page:

```
<TABLE ALIGN="CENTER">
<TR HEIGHT="20">
<TD VALIGN="TOP" COLSPAN="2">

<%out.print(ahrefPopupLink[0][1]); %>

</TD>
</TR>

</TABLE>
```

This is the data that is store in the database:

```
<a href="JavaScript:popupHTMLWin('pdf/filename.pdf', 'popupName', 
'8080');"> <font color="#FF0040"><i><p> link name </p></i></font></a>
```

I can see the links to the pop up windows but none work.

This is the error I can see in the developer tools on chrome. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'Window': Unable to open a window with invalid URL

Comment: I am not web dev so I can be wrong, but are you sure `/pdf/filename.pdf/` should end with `/`?

Comment: Hey Pshemo! I'm a beginner web developer. I just tried what you suggested and its giving me invalid or unexpected token error. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Maybe check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812161/opening-popup-windows-in-html

Comment: Thank you Chuck that link gave me a working solution!